# how to show [object Object] result in view angular 2

Tags: angular

in ts

```
getSumOfExpense(key:string,qty=0){
    return this.db.list('testExpenses/-L01TCiyqdQKrKq9oA8L')
    .map(cfs => {
      cfs.map(cf => {
          this.db.object('testExpenses/-L01TCiyqdQKrKq9oA8L/cf.$key')
          .subscribe(d => {
              cf.amount = d;
          });
        return cf;
      });
      cfs.forEach(cf => {
          qty += cf.amount;
      });
     return {qty}
    })
```

in view

```
<strong> {{expSvc.getSumOfExpense(caseFile.$key)}} </strong>
```

my result like this [object Object] how to show in view

Comment: Your question shows [no attempt](//idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) of solving the problem. If you have made an attempt, you should edit our question to detail exactly what you did, researched for, and point to any links that were helpful but that did not answer your question. If you’ve tried to code a solution, that should be added in an edit. Your attempts should be turned into a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so it is clear to read and understand. Also read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extremely easy thing to tackle. Please read the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#jsonpipe) before even asking a question.

Anyways, just use the `json` pipe in your curly brackets:

```html
<strong> {{expSvc.getSumOfExpense(caseFile.$key) | json}} </strong>
```

Comment: you can be sure i used the json pipe as you said. But an error occurred, 
"Converting circular structure to JSON". Thank you for your suggestion anyway

Comment: **"Converting circular structure to JSON"**

Comment: I meant the **full stacktrace**. Anyways, what does your JSON structure look like?